# which is more optimize? many records or one record with a CLOB column?

Tags: java, oracle, clob

I want to send notifications to my clients async
so I have created a notification table in oracle and I have a job that reads the data from the notification table and sends them to receivers.
The notification table has a data column (the data that should be sent in the notification).

for maintaining receivers I have 2 ways :

1- a CLOB column that is JSON object of receivers ids (an array of ids converted to JSON) after I read this record I have to convert the CLOB column content to an array of String.

2- having a notification record for each receiver (the receiver column is a String field that contains one receiver token).

The question is which approach is more optimize? 1 or 2?

Comment: What are you trying to optimize for?

Comment: @StephenC time optimization. I want to know which way is faster? inserting and fetching many records to/ from DB, or inserting one record with a CLOB column and fetching it and parsing the CLOB column?

Comment: Which Oracle version do you have in mind?

Comment: It is hard to say.  It will depend on various factors such as the average size and number of the strings and the relative speed of the database versus the client.  I suggest that you do some testing.

Comment: for using clob you can use this SO for testing https://stackoverflow.com/a/61655250/1297792